# AS3 removing event listeners

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, addeventlistener

I have a basic question about manually removing event listeners in actionscript 3.

If I have a function like:

```
    private function doStuff(event : Event):void
    {

        //let them save
        var f:FileReference = new FileReference();
        f.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,saveDone);
        f.save(mp3Encoder.mp3Data,"output.mp3");

    }
```

How do I remove the event listeners when the saveDone function is called? Normally I just change the "add" to "remove" like:

```
f.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,saveDone);
```

However, f is a local variable, and I can't get to it after the doStuff function ends.

```
    private function saveDone(ev:Event){
        f.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,saveDone);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe try to reference the original object via the "target" property of the event?  I haven't tried it, but something akin to:

```
private function saveDone(ev:Event){
var originalFR:FileReference = ev.target as FileReference;    
originalFR.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveDone);
}
```

But I may be completely off.

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative is to declare the `FileReference` as a member variable and add the `EventHandler` in the constructor. You can remove all the `EventHandlers` in the destructor.

Comment: Ah thanks for the input. I had been doing that a lot, but didn't know which was better practice. I know I'm not good at flash and AS3, but my code seems messy either way. A ton of member variables simply used to have an event was getting confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's also a good back-up to add a weak reference so that the listener is removed and garbage collected automatically when there are no references left pointing at it.

```
f.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,saveDone,false,0,true);
```

However, it's always best to make sure you manually remove a listener.